# Why does exec 2>file.txt redirect the standard input?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I am trying to understand `exec`, which is used for redirection of stdio as far as I understood. Now, if I enter:

```
exec 2>file.txt
```

My shell changes to only showing a text cursor icon. Now everything I type is redirected to `file.txt`, including the "user@computer:directory$" part of the shell. This is confusing to me, since I thought that `2>` redirects only the `stderr` (while `>`, or `1>` redirects the `stdout`). So why does `exec 2>` redirect everything?

Comment: Type `ls` and press Enter. Is the output of `ls` in that file?

Comment: `exec 2>` redirects standard error and only standard error. It so happens that the shell displays the prompt on standard error.

Comment: @muru No it does not, it does however contain my input "user@computer:~$ ls", which is obviously std in (or is it?)...

Comment: @AlexP how come, then, the file *also* contains my input (i.e. the commands I type) and not just the standard prompt plus stderr?

Comment: @AlphaOmega the commands you type are also output by the shell somewhere, right? Otherwise how would you see them?

Comment: @AlphaOmega: The shell uses a library called `readline` to read your commands. `readline` sets the terminal in raw mode, that is, the terminal does not iself echo the characters typed; the characters you type are read from standard input and echoed to standard error, or, in the case of characters such as up arrow, backspace, control-R, etc. some action is performed instead of echoing the character.

Comment: @AlexP Hi Alex, where is the knowledge, that stdin is echoed to stderr, referenced?

Comment: @Frank: Standard input is not echoed to standard error, in general. *If* standard input is a terminal, then Bash uses GNU Readline to provide the nice command line history and editing features we all love. How this works is documented by the the documentation of the [GNU Readline library](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)... and of course practical observations such as that which prompted this question.

Comment: @AlexP Yes, I observed it today and searched for some explanations. Thank you very much!